# Propagar datos y estado con Viewmodel en Java Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewmodel

Tengo implementado en un ˋViewModelˋ para obtener las apps instaladas por el usuario, lo obtengo con un ˋAsyncTaskˋ, en la actividad tengo como observador el cambio.

```
public class PackageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Float, Boolean> {

    private WeakReference<Application> weakApplication;

    private MutableLiveData<List<ApplicationInfo>> packagesListLiveData;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> packagesList;

    PackageAsyncTask(Application application, MutableLiveData<List<ApplicationInfo>> _packagesList) {
        weakApplication = new WeakReference<>(application);
        packagesListLiveData = _packagesList;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (weakApplication.get() != null) {
            final PackageManager pm = weakApplication.get().getPackageManager(); //get a list of installed apps.
            packagesList = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        packagesListLiveData.setValue(packagesList);
    }
}
```

Me gustaria tambien capturar el estado de la tarea en curso, para así mostrar el estado de carga.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución es empaquetar el estado y los datos en un objeto compuesto.

```
public class Resource<T> {

    @NonNull
    private final Status status;
    @Nullable
    private final T data;
    @Nullable
    private final AppException exception;

    private Resource(@NonNull Status status, @Nullable T data,  @Nullable AppException exception) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Nullable
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Nullable
    public AppException getException() {
        return exception;
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> SUCCESS(@NonNull T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.SUCCESS, data, null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Resource<T> SUCCESS(@NonNull List<T> data) {
        return new Resource<T>(Status.SUCCESS, (T) data, null);
    }


    public static <T> Resource<T> ERROR(AppException exception, @Nullable T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.ERROR, data, exception);
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> LOADING(@Nullable T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.LOADING, data, null);
    }


    public enum Status {SUCCESS, ERROR, LOADING}
}
```

AppException.java

```
public class AppException extends Exception {
    public AppException(Throwable t) {
        super(t);
    }
}
```

**Su uso**

- *Resource.LOADING(null)* para propagar que está procesando
- *Resource.SUCCES(lista_de_datos)* para propagar finalización de la tarea y sus datos
- *Resource.ERROR(excepcio,null)* para propagar un error en la carga de datos

Cambiar el tipo de datos a recbir por

```
MutableLiveData<Resource<Tipo_de_datos>>
```

Dentro de los estados de ˋAsyncTaskˋ

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        packagesListLiveData.setValue(Resource.LOADING(null));
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        packagesListLiveData.setValue(Resource.SUCCESS(packagesList));
    }
```

#### Observador de los datos

```
packageViewModel.getAllPackages().observe(this, new Observer<Resource<ApplicationInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Resource resource) {

                switch (resource.status) {
                    case LOADING:
                        //Mostrar la vista de carga
                        break;
                    case SUCCESS:
                        if (resource.data == null) {
                            //Mostrar la vista de sin datos
                        } else {
                            List<ApplicationInfo> dataList = (List<ApplicationInfo>) resource.data;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Total items: " + dataList.size());
                        }
                }
            }
```